# Android Facebook Share and wall post using share url in Webview not working

Tags: android, facebook, webview, share

I m using share to Facebook using the following url and load that url in web view but i cant able to type comments and also some time post button is also not working.

```
 http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=xxx&t=yyy&refsrc=http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php
```

Can any one provide good solution or an alternative for this (plz give example for using api for facebook share and wall post).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a quick tutorial about how to integrate official Facebook Android SDK into your Android apps.

Check it out [here](http://thetechnib.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-facebook-integration.html). I feel it'll help you

Comment: So sorry. This is VERY old and the blog I had doesn't even exist now